# Verifying POST data sent from same server WITHOUT using a token using PHP?

Tags: php, post

For reasons beyond the scope of this post, I would like to verify in PHP if post data was sent from the same server, but I would like to avoid using a token. If completely necessary, I can use one, but I would be very helpful if I didn't have to.

Is this possible? If not, why?

Thanks!

Comment: post data being sent from the **client's PC**, dude. Go figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can check the remote address for the IP address of the request sender using [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Do it like this:

```
if( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $your_Server_IP_Address)
     echo 'From same server';
else
     echo 'from different server';
```

Comment: What's the reason of sending post data from the same server?

Comment: But YOU answers it, not the OP! Do you understand the question? If yes - why can't you answer me? If not - why the heck you answer at all?

Comment: @Col, How can I know why OP is sending post request to same server. He asked for "how to know if request is from same server" which I answered. Yes, I do understand the question and replied according to my understanding.

Comment: this question is nonsense. You cannot understand it. But of course it doesn't matter if your only intention is to get reputation points.

Comment: @Col, I believe your account is hacked. Because the "Col Shrapnel" that I know on SO does not responds like this. As about the "nonsense status" of this question, if you believe that the question is nonsense, you can vote to close it. The issues you're raising here, should be raised to the OP. He already said that why he is doing it is beyond the scope. Why fight over that. All he needs is our collective knowledge on SO and we should answer the questions which we can answer. And, maybe if reputation points got converted to money, I would be reaping them. But, they're not.

Comment: @shamittomar - haha ... u just need to expand both answer and question to see the downvote, `0=-1+1`

Comment: @ajreal, do you too believe that the question is non-sense and should not be answered ?

Comment: I'm just trying to make sure that http://example1.com doesn't send a post to http://myapp.com. That's all.

Comment: @Allen, then just check the IP address of example1.com with the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to check if the request is originating from example1.com or not.

Comment: @shamittomar - no comments, just to indicate @Col account is not hacked, and he did the usual downvote too (how can he missed that ?)

Comment: Thanks for your help. In other news, it sounds like someone got coal in their stocking! ;)

Comment: Pretty nice Christmas going for me.

Comment: @Col: Im actually facing the same issue. Its not really an odd thing. In my case a flash app will be posting to an API. But the API is only for use by that flash app which resides on the same server. Because the API isnt anything terribly serious we decided to forgo some token auth scheme and just rely on checking IP's like the example Shamittomar gave. Its not a nonsense question.

Comment: @prodigitalson yup, you are facing the same issue of ignorance. A flash app resides in the user's browser, not server.

Comment: @Col: Normally that would be true... but something happens in the flash app/server and the post does not come from the client but rather the server. How that happens im not sure but by the time the request gets to me its originating from the server. Probably means there is a better way to integrate, but i work with the specs Im given, especially since this is an add-on to something existing.